# Google Analytics considers Gleam App's loading time as a Page Loading time.

Tags: google-analytics, performance, page-speed, google-pagespeed

I have embedded the Gleam App widget on my client's website. Let me inform about the Gleam app first. The Gleam App is used for the Giveaways. The participant has to complete certain entries to get eligible for the Giveaway. It takes some time for the participant to finish all the entries.

After the manual experiment, I found the landing page, including the Gleam App, loads in about 4-5 seconds.

However, when I opened Site Speed Report in Google Analytics, it shows more than 70 seconds loading time for that page. So I guess GA also considers the time till the participant is completing the entries. Because for each entry, the information is loaded from Gleam's server.

This messes up my entire data.

The page is actually fully loaded once the Gleam app is loaded. I don't want to count the loading time till someone is participating in the Giveaway.

So how to avoid the loading time from third party application? Could anyone guide me how can I do this?

Comment: Are you using defer properly when using JS libraries? You can track this by finding the order in which your JS scripts are firing.

Comment: Hi @Prasad usually the entire page loads in 4-5 seconds. I also checked with PingDom. The issue is mainly because of the Gleam app. The basic Gleamapp loads within seconds, but the Google analytics also calculates the time till the participants is performing various tasks. I want to avoid this and really not sure how to do this.

Comment: There is an option to hide these pages from the Analytics report. But is there anything by which I can solve this issue?

Comment: I havent used Gleamapp, so I am asking you to check. Does Gleam on its own use GA? Could it be using the default GA object and thus sending additional page load JS events which might be impacting your data?

Comment: Hi @Prasad no, it doesn't have its own GA. I found that its own FB, Twitter, Google API itself takes a longer time to load. So right now I am just hiding these pages in the GA report so it won't impact on the Avg loading time.